# Dynamic variables in select query

Tags: spring, postgresql

There is a transactionReceipt variable in my request that is taken from the product, i.e. product.gettransactionReceipt (), how can I send this value to the transactionReceipt which in the request? transactionReceipt is one of json that is user field

```
// TODO check another users bought
if (!purchased.contains(product.getProductId())) {
  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  String transactionReceipt = product.getTransactionReceipt();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("DECLARE transactionReceipt ; Select username from user WHERE  info -> 'purshasedProducts' ->> 'transactionReceipt' = 'transactionReceipt");
```

Comment: You can't use `DECLARE` in plain SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `PreparedStatement` instead, and pass the `transactionReceipt` into it as a parameter. Likes:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("Select username from user WHERE  info -> 'purshasedProducts' ->> 'transactionReceipt' = ?");

String transactionReceipt = product.getTransactionReceipt();
st.setString(1, transactionReceipt);

ResultSet execute = st.executeQuery();
```